Should I, not American, use a pseudonym to publish a book set in America?
I'm Brazilian and I have never set foot in America, but I decided to set the story of my first book in a fictional town in Maine. After some research, it seemed like the ideal setting, so I did it, why not?
I'm working on the last few edits before publishing it, but something came to my mind. The idea is to publish it in my native language first (Portuguese), without megalomaniac pretensions, and maybe publish it in English at some point.
The sound of my last name is not at all similar to anything in English (LEMES), so any reader could immediately think that I am maybe 1. a foreigner writing with a US setting from distance, what can turn them off from reading or 2. a foreigner living in the US.
For publishing in Portuguese, it doesn't seem like a problem, but would it be better to choose a pseudonym more comfortable for a native English speaker? Will I suffer discrimination from readers just because of my "non-English" family name, and should I consider this approach instead of my real name, or am I overthinking it?
I know this is not a very objective question, but perhaps there is a prevailing opinion, or even a known similar case. It would already help.

Frame challenge: is the pseudonym you've picked out exciting enough?

I don't have one :D I was thinking of simply translating my last name (Carvalho, to 'Oak').

You might be overthinking it.... I am in favor of using 1 consistent name as a brand, and there are many reasons you might not want your 'brand' to be your private legal name... imho, there are many factors that are far more important in choosing a brandname than a fear of offending imaginary xenophobes in Maine. Try to turn such questions around to a positive that can benefit you – is a unique brandname better/worse than a comfort/familiar name? What demographic do you need to appeal to, for your brand to sell?


Non-indigenous North Americans have names from all over the world, not just from Britain. If your language reads like that of a native speaker (which it must, even if were a translation from the Portuguese) and you describe North American culture accurately, no one will assume you aren't American unless you tell them.

There are readers who like to read foreign literature and those who don't and those who don't care either way. I have no percentages, but every decision will attract some readers and put others off. Personally, I wouldn't worry about it.

In the long run, how are you going to do interviews, what will you write in your biography, how will you interact with fans? Are you going to lie? What if your true origin is uncovered, your readers are disappointed by your untruth, and turn away from you?

I believe (but cannot prove) that books set in a foreign locale but written by someone not native to that place often lack some feel of being "authentic". Books by foreigners set in my home country almost always seem a little too superficial and stereotyped and lacking some insight or native coloring. I avoid such books. When I want to read about my home, I want it to be "real".

You have a short, memorable, unique-in-the-US name that would make a good author brand. I wouldn't replace it with a mediocre pseudonym.



Good points. I'd be curious about a foreigner writing about Brazil, but in the end, it would be funny - in a bad way - if it was a mess of references and stereotypes. It reminds me of some video games that tried and failed to be authentic (like Max Payne 3, for people who play games). I'll mark it as answer, thank you.
